# Confused in an expression $B_{eff}=-\frac{V}{C}\times E$ in Sakurai

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I am confused in a term while reading spin orbit interaction from Sakurai. He said whenever a moving charge is subjected to an electric field, it feels effective magnetic field given by $$B_{eff}=-\frac{V}{C}\times E$$ eq 5.3.14 in the book. How one can obtain this expression?

Comment: This is a result from classical electromagnetism I believe. Also, I think your result is in CGS units, since in SI, the electric and magnetic fields don't have the same units. Feynman does it in a very interesting way [here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html).

Comment: Biot-Savart law... the electron "feels" the moving nucleus in the distance moving with the same speed $v$ thus creating a magnetic field for the electron related by Coulomb's law to the electric field.

Answer (score 0):

You compute the Lorentz transformation of the ${\bf E}$ and ${\bf B}$ fields:

$$
E_x(x,y,z,t) \mapsto 
   E_x(x' ,y, z, t'),\\
   E_y(x,y,z,t) \mapsto   
   E_y(x', y, z, t') \cosh s  - 
B_z(x', y, z, t',)     \sinh s\\
   E_z (x,y,z,t) \mapsto 
  E_z(x', y, z, t')   \cosh s + 
    B_y(x', y, z, t')  \sinh s,\\
 B_x(x,y,z,t) \mapsto
   B_x(x', y, z, t')\\
B_y(x,y,z,t) \mapsto
B_y(x', y, z, t')   \cosh s + 
    E_z(x', y, z, t')  \sinh  s\\
  B_z(x,y,z,t) \mapsto
   B_z(x' y, z, t')  \cosh s- 
 E_y(x', y, z, t')   \sinh s,
$$
where $s$ is the rapidity defined by $v= \tanh s$ and  the Lorentz transformation is
$$
x' = x\, \cosh  s+ t\, \sinh s\\
t' = t\,\cosh s- x\, \sinh s.
$$
If you do this you find (from the last two lines of the transformations) that a pure   ${\bf E}$ field in  lab frame looks like there is a $|B|= \sinh s |E|$ field when viewed in the moving frame.